# how cut folder using DocumentFile android Java

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

I have folder,inside which I have another folder, in which I have files and folders.

```
/Folder|
       |->Folder |
                 |->Folders
                 |->Files
```

How I can move all content from inside folder to top,and after that delete inside folder.

```
/Folder|
       |->Folder  (Delete)
       |->Folders (Move Here)  
       |->Files   (Move Here)
```

I know, how to do this for normal File,

but I don't know how to do this for [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile), because in my project I use this for manage files.

Comment: Like in all file systems you need to be able to copy a file and to delete one. And to delete a folder. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: how to get full path to the folder,using DocumentFile?

Comment: Of which folder? You have a lot of folders i see.  And why a 'full path' ? DocumentFile works with content schemes. With uri's.